# Pagination and search bar not showing at all in Data Table plugin

Tags: pagination, datatables

I am trying to work with the most basic Data Table example.
The main problem is  that the pagination does not work, it doesn't even show. I can't even see the "Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries" in the Zero-initialisation example from their website.

Has anybody experienced this problem?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit : I am populating my table dynamically.

Comment: Can you post the code that initialises the datatable?

Comment: $('#employees_table').dataTable();         This is what I have in my $(document).ready(function() )

Comment: Here is a basic example based on what you've said: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/gy3cvdwg/).  Without any more information I can't really help, but it sounds like the datatables libraries aren't loading.  Can you check that?

Comment: How can I check that? Also, my results from the call to the server are being displayed, but there is no pagination. This is my main problem.

Comment: You can check in Firebug or similar, use the 'Net' panel to check that the datatables js and css file have loaded. Again, without any more information I can't really help, but as you have now told us that the server results _are_ showing, and as your datatables initialisation code doesn't have an ajax call, I'm guessing that you're populating the table successfully using another method, and applying the datatable plugin.  I'm still sure that it's that the libraries are missing...

Comment: The CSS is loading, but the JavaScript doesn't appear in the Net tab, under the Javascript option. So you are right.

Comment: Make sure that the files aren't cached by doing a hard refresh(Ctrl-F5).  Cached files won't appear in the Net tab which might make you think they aren't being loaded.

Comment: I did the hard refresh, still no loading.

Comment: OK, so you need to add them in the same manner as your other js files, see the link in the 3rd comment if you're not sure.

Comment: I did add them .. I can't figure out what's wrong. My table is in a JSP page, but that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Now, the javascript appears under the Net tab

Comment: Have you also got jquery.js loaded?

Comment: Well, I'm running out of ideas! Couple of things to check - jquery.js should be loaded before datatables.js. What versions of datatables are you using, and what version of jquery are you loading?

Comment: I am using dataTables 1.90 and jQuery 2.1.3

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle with the versions you mention and it works fine: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/gy3cvdwg/5/).  There must be something else that's causing the problem.  Sorry I'm unable to help you further.

Comment: So you have pagination in the fiddle you posted?

Comment: Yes, have you not tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It works fine. So, there is a problem in my own code. I hope I can figure it out soon. Thank you for all your help, time and kindness!

Comment: So many comments - all could have been spared if OP had given a code example from the beginning.

Comment: dataTables 1.90 and jQuery 2.1.3  is a very bad combination. Upgrade your dataTables to 1.10.x.